# Filter object items with query string Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have an object with a list of products and I want to filter it by using a GET method with a provided query string.

I need to create a route to the products "/products" and I need to get the list of objects filtered by a "max" price which is provided in a query string.
For instance, if the url provided is "/products/max=2000" I want to get back the list of products that does not cost over that set max.

I've been trying without success something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const products = [
    {
        nome: 'Motorola Moto E6 Plus',
        preco: 14999
    },
    {
        nome: 'Motorola Moto G7',
        preco: 19999
    },
    {
        nome: 'Alcatel 5033A',
        preco: 6999
    },
    {
        nome: 'Samsung Galaxy A50',
        preco: 33499
    }
];

const filterPrice = {
    viewCelular: (req, res)=>{
        let {celular, preco} = req.query;

        res.send(products)
    }
}

router.get('/products', (req, res) => { 

    res.send(req.query.filterPrice)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you need to pass `req`, `res` in `filterPrice` function and destruct `max` from `req.query` and apply filter then send response.
Your url would be like `http://localhost:3000/products?max=2000`.
Here is an example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
const products = [
  {
    nome: 'Motorola Moto E6 Plus',
    preco: 14999
  },
  {
    nome: 'Motorola Moto G7',
    preco: 19999
  },
  {
    nome: 'Alcatel 5033A',
    preco: 6999
  },
  {
    nome: 'Samsung Galaxy A50',
    preco: 33499
  },
  {
    nome: 'Smartwatch',
    preco: 1700
  }
];
const filterPrice = {
  viewCelular: (req, res) => {
    let { celular, preco, max } = req.query;

    res.send(products.filter(e => e.preco <= max))
  }
}
app.get('/products/', (req, res) => {
  filterPrice.viewCelular(req, res)
})
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port);
console.log('I am ready and listening on %d', port);
```

Answer (score 0):

this function return list by filtered with max.

```
function maxfilter(max){
  return products.filter(x=>x.preco<=max);
}
```

and call it in your filterPrice

```
 const filterPrice = {
        viewCelular: (req, res)=>{
            let {celular, preco, max} = req.query;

            res.send(maxfilter(max))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use url params like `router.get('/products/:max')` and you must send "/procucts/2000" to get the results then you just need to use [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in the callback:

```
let filterArr = products.filter( product => { return product.preco <= req.params.max })
```

and now filterArr is the array that you want and it's ready to use.You can also use sort method if you want to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) this array and make things more efficient:

```
filterArr.sort((a,b)=>{
   return a.preco - b.preco;
});
```